# Trigger Click on Input when Label is Clicked in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

---

I am create a widget in jquery colorbox, it allows user to load file. The way of how I implemented it is followed:

I have an input tag with `type='file'` and style with `visibility:hidden`,
then, I created two labels both of them has 'for' attribute point to the file upload input element, which are styled like button. so when user get click on it, browser opens select file popup for them.

This approach works for IE9, IE10. but it is not working in IE8, clicking on the label seems not even trigger the click event on the input element.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You won't be able to trigger it. You'll have to position the input over top the label and make it opaque...the user will end up clicking on the input but they won't actually see it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian, I did exactly you said above, and it works now.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that:

1) You use a label with a `for` attribute pointing to your input by `id`.

2) Your input is not having a CSS `display:none`. Try using `width:0`, `height:0`, `margin:-10000px`, etc in order to hide it.

This seems to work for me at the moment for IE8.

Comment: correct. or use `position: fixed; left: -9999px;` to move the element out of viewport.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$('label').on('click',function() {
    $('input').trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't use javascript trigger the click event, because of IE8 will think it is not safe, so during the upload, I will get an access denied error.

Comment: Hmmm...perhaps it has something to do with `visibility: hidden`. Have you tried keeping the visibility and absolute positioning it very far off the page? Maybe then the label would work.